# setup.cfg declaring console_scripts errors with "Entry points must be listed in groups"

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to configure setuptools to create a console entry point for my package, following [the docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html), and ending up with [the following config](https://github.com/tomasaschan/hiplog/blob/master/setup.cfg#L15-L17):

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts = 
    hiplog = hiplog.scripts.hiplog:cli
```

But when I `pip install -e .` in my repository, pip raises the following error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2857, in get_entry_map
    ep_map = self._ep_map
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2815, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _ep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 397, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 75, in install_given_reqs
    uninstalled_pathset = requirement.uninstall(
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 685, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 571, in from_dist
    console_scripts = dist.get_entry_map(group='console_scripts')
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2859, in get_entry_map
    ep_map = self._ep_map = EntryPoint.parse_map(
  File "/home/taschan/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/envs/hiplog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2531, in parse_map
    raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same symptom, and the root cause turned out to be a botched `pip install -e .` from a previous run. Deleting the `projectname.egg-info` directory did the trick.